# Bokeh secondary y range affecting primary y range

Tags: python-3.x, data-visualization, bokeh

I'm working on building a Bokeh plot using bokeh.plotting. I have two series with a shared index that I want to plot two vertical bars for. When I use a single bar everything works fine, but when I add a second y range and the second bar it seems to be impacting the primary y range (changes the vales from 0 to 4), and my second vbar() overlays the first. Any assistance on why the bars overlap instead of being side by side and why the second series/yaxis seems to impact the first even though they are separate would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import bokeh.plotting as bp
from bokeh.models import NumeralTickFormatter, HoverTool, Range1d, LinearAxis

df_x_series = ['a','b','c']
fig = bp.figure(title='WIP',x_range=df_x_series,plot_width=1200,plot_height=600,toolbar_location='below',toolbar_sticky=False,tools=['reset','save'],active_scroll=None,active_drag=None,active_tap=None)
fig.title.align= 'center'
fig.extra_y_ranges = {'c_count':Range1d(start=0, end=10)}
fig.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name='c_count'), 'right')
fig.vbar(bottom=0, top=[1,2,3], x=['a','b','c'], color='blue', legend='Amt', width=0.3, alpha=0.5)
fig.vbar(bottom=0, top=[5,7,8], x=['a','b','c'], color='green', legend='Ct', width=0.3, alpha=0.8, y_range_name='c_count')
fig.yaxis[0].formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format='0.0')
bp.output_file('bar.html')
bp.show(fig)
```

[image: bokeh plot]

Comment: Realize that my bars are overlapping due to the shared index, but can't offset them with the example shown here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/plotting/file/bar_chart.py as I'm using a categorical axis of strings. Any ideas of offsetting these would be appreciated. Also could fix the primary y axis range by hard coding, but was hoping to avoid that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the plot I believe you want:
[image]

And here's the code:

```
import bokeh.plotting as bp
from bokeh.models import NumeralTickFormatter, Range1d, LinearAxis

df_x_series = ['a', 'b', 'c']
fig = bp.figure(
    title='WIP',
    x_range=df_x_series,
    y_range=Range1d(start=0, end=4),
    plot_width=1200, plot_height=600,
    toolbar_location='below',
    toolbar_sticky=False,
    tools=['reset', 'save'],
    active_scroll=None, active_drag=None, active_tap=None
)
fig.title.align = 'center'
fig.extra_y_ranges = {'c_count': Range1d(start=0, end=10)}
fig.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name='c_count'), 'right')
fig.vbar(bottom=0, top=[1, 2, 3], x=['a:0.35', 'b:0.35', 'c:0.35'], color='blue', legend='Amt', width=0.3, alpha=0.5)
fig.vbar(bottom=0, top=[5, 7, 8], x=['a:0.65', 'b:0.65', 'c:0.65'], color='green', legend='Ct', width=0.3, alpha=0.8, y_range_name='c_count')
fig.yaxis[0].formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format='0.0')
bp.output_file('bar.html')
bp.show(fig)
```

A couple of notes:

- Categorical axes are currently a bit (ahem) ugly in Bokeh. We hope to address this in the coming months. Each one has a scale of 0 - 1 after a colon which allows you to move things left and right. So I move the first bar to the left by 0.3/2 and the second bar to the right by 0.3/2 (0.3 because that's the width you had used)
- The y_range changed because you were using the default y_range for your initial y_range which is a DataRange1d. DataRange uses all the data for the plot to pick its values and adds some padding which is why it was starting at below 0 and going up to the max of your new data. By manually specifying a range in the figure call you get around this.

Thanks for providing a code sample to work from :D

Comment: This was made with 0.12.3 that just came out.

Comment: Thank you this answer is exactly what I had been attempting with this. I'll work on integrating this with some different graphs I had been attempting to create dynamically with Bokeh.

Comment: FWIW: This solution doesn't seem to work with newer versions of Bokeh. (I'm seeing it break in 0.12.10.)  I'm trying to figure out what changed, and whether this behavior is still supported somehow. I'll come back w/ updates of what I find, but if anyone knows better than me in the meantime I'd love a pointer in the right direction. :)

Comment: Update: Further investigation show that this sample code (and our code which was based on it) breaks beginning in release 0.12.7. There seems to be a new "visual dodge" feature that was added/documented then. Maybe that's the new preferred way to go?

https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#visual-dodge